# How to fix Cordova Android emulator problem?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-studio, vue.js

I use Cordova and VueJs in my project. 
I installed Android studio and Android emulator

if I run the command

```
cordova emulate android
```

I see only

```
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_6_API_28
Waiting for emulator to start...
```

After 30 min+ wait, android emulator still does not run. 
How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

did you download android API 28(google api) and x86 Images for API 28.

Please first download if not download both

[image]